# Why is ggplotly ruining my legends from ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am creating a ggplot visual and am using ggplotly for interactivity. The ggplot visual is fine, but when I use it with ggplotly the legend clips...

Below are the two visuals I am discussing:

ggplot:

[image]

ggplotly:

[image]

My code:

```
plotall <- ggplot(vacgdp3, aes(x=GDP, y=people_vaccinated_per_hundred, size = total_vaccinations, color = continent, text = paste0("People Vaccinated Per Hundred: ", people_vaccinated_per_hundred, "\nCountry: ", country))) +
geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
scale_x_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "Trillion", scale = 1e-12))+
ylab("People Vaccinated Per Hundred")+
xlab("GDP per Capita")



ggplotly(plotall, tooltip = c("x", "text"))
```

And I uploaded a txt file that was created using dput() for the dataset:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0a7z9qfq20h91m/Vac.txt?dl=0

I have been trying to format the legends with ggplotly but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, any tips on how I can improve my question asking would also be welcomed, as I am quite new!

Comment: Set the plot size to be smaller. For example: `ggplotly(df, height = 300, width=300)`

Comment: This shrinks the plot but it is still clipped just the same...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the details but instead of adding the legend title via `ggplot` and `ggplotly` you could remove the legend titles from the ggplot and add it via `layout`. This way `plotly` will take care of the length of the legend title and increase the margin as needed:

```
library(plotly)

plotall <- ggplot(vacgdp3, aes(x=GDP, y=people_vaccinated_per_hundred, size = total_vaccinations, color = continent, text = paste0("People Vaccinated Per Hundred: ", people_vaccinated_per_hundred, "\nCountry: ", country))) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "Trillion", scale = 1e-12))+
  ylab("People Vaccinated Per Hundred") +
  xlab("GDP per Capita") +
  labs(color = NULL, size = NULL)

ggplotly(plotall, tooltip = c("x", "text")) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(title = list(text = "Legend title long long long long<br>")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This makes the continent legend look great! Do you know what happened to the bubble size legend? Shouldn't it be showing both?

Comment: Have a closer look. Actually the size legend is there, but it got merged with the color legend and shows up as different sized legend keys probably showing the (unweighted) mean (??) size of countries per continent. Moreover, you have to keep in mind that overall ggplotly does a good job in converting the ggplot to a plotly object but plotly is not interactive ggplot, it's plotly and therefore there are some restrictions on what could be achieved.