# Why is ggplotly still ruining my legends from ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I do have a similar behavior than [Why is ggplotly ruining my legends from ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176949/why-is-ggplotly-ruining-my-legends-from-ggplot) but failed to fix it.

Legend is changed by `ggplotly()`, how could I prevent that or edit the legend?

ggplot :

[image]

ggplotly :
[image]

Code :

```
library(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(123)
X <- rpois(20,3)
fit.p.mme <- fitdist(data = X, distr = "pois", method = "mme")
fit.p.mle <- fitdist(data = X, distr = "pois", method = "mle")

g1 <- cdfcomp(list(fit.p.mme, fit.p.mle), addlegend = TRUE, legendtext = c("P MME", "P MLE"), plotstyle = "ggplot")
g1 <- g1 + theme_gray()
g1
g1 %>% ggplotly()
```

Tryed to edit labels in `g1$data$ind` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the names manually in a Plotly build.

To find out what names came from where I built the plot and ran `lapply` to output the names and legend groups. In plotly, discrete color assignments will get their own trace. So the name of the trace is typically the name in the legend *when it's built*.

I didn't need to call `ggplotly()` first, either.

```
g2 <- plotly_build(g1)

invisible(
  lapply(1:length(g2$x$data),
         function(j) {
           message(paste0(j, " ", g2$x$data[[j]]$name, " & ",
                          g2$x$data[[j]]$legendgroup))
         })
)

#   1  & 
#   2  & 
#   3  & 
#   4  & 
#   5 (pois,1) & (pois,1)
#   6 (pois.1,1) & (pois.1,1)
```

So there are 6 traces, and these are their names (less the ampersand that I pasted in there).

You can change these names directly.

```
g2$x$data[[5]]$name <- "P MME"
g2$x$data[[5]]$legendgroup <- "P MME"
g2$x$data[[6]]$name <- "P MLE"
g2$x$data[[6]]$legendgroup <- "P MLE"
```

If you wanted the legend centered on the y-axis with the plot background color, you can do that here, too.

```
g2$x$layout$legend$y <- .5  # if you want to move the legend to the middle
g2$x$layout$legend$bgcolor <- g2$x$layout$plot_bgcolor # to use the same bg color

g2 # let's see it
```

[image]

It's definitely not the same, but it's closer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion. It is quite complex since we do have to identify the index of the "traces" we want to modify thanks to `plotly_build()`. Are the fourth one always empty?
It would be easier I think to modify the labels prior to the plotly step, do you know where plotly retrieve the labels from in this case?

Comment: Every plot is different.  In this particular case, it took the names from `ind`. When Plotly validates the string names, it checks for strings that violate the conventions of JS, D3, HTML, etc along with the uniqueness within the plot. I'm sure I'm just brushing the surface.

Comment: Validated your answer. Thanks.